# Value of list attribute of radio button from scriplet in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, radio-button, jstl, struts, ognl

I want to read a key and value of `list` from a loop.
Below is the code snippet that I tried but it's not working.

```
<c:forEach items="${mylist}" var="title">
    <c:set var="id" value="${title.key.id}"/>
      <%Integer idInt = (Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("id");
      String idStr = "";
      if(idInt != null && idInt.intValue() > 0){
      idStr = idInt.toString();
      }%>
<s:radio theme="simple" name="selectedOption" list="#{idStr:title.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Why sriplets? Why `forEach`? What are trying to do?

Comment: @AleksandrM: I am trying to read key and value of list from loop.

Comment: Key of the list? Do you mean index?

Comment: @AleksandrM yes index(listkey) and value

Comment: In that case what is this `title.key.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<c:forEach items="${mylist}" var="title">
  <s:radio theme="simple" name="selectedOption" list="#{#attr.title.key.id:#attr.title.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

The variable `title` is in the page scope, but you don't need a scriptlet to access it.